# Mongo DB showing erroneous count

Tags: mongodb, count, robo3t

I am trying to find count of entries in a mongo collection. I am using robomongo as the querying platform. These are my queries:

```
db.getCollection('non_time_reduced_price_points').count()
```

[image: Image1]

```
db.getCollection('non_time_reduced_price_points').find().count()
```

[image: Image2]

```
db.getCollection('non_time_reduced_price_points').find({vt: {'$exists': true}}).count()
```

[image: Image3]

The first 2 queries are giving 63967 as answer while last query is giving 63975.

How's it possible?

Comment: How does it work with aggregation? E.g. `db.non_time_reduced_price_points.aggregate([{ $facet: {total: [{$group: {_id: null, cnt: {$sum: 1}}}], vt: [{$match:{vt:{$exists: true}}}, {$group: {_id: null, cnt: {$sum: 1}}}]}}])`

Comment: @AlexBlex: It returned 63975.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. It have to return 2 numbers.